# how to create static class List property inside static class

Tags: c#

I have created following class:

```
       public static class Current
        {
            public static class User
            {
                public static int UserID { get; set; }
                public static string UserName { get; set; }
                public static List<UserRole> Role { get; set; }
            }
            public static class UserRole
            {
                public static int RoleID { get; set; }
                public static string RoleName { get; set; }
            }
       }
```

But it will gives me an error: in this line

```
public static List<UserRole> Role { get; set; }
```

**Error    1   'Framework.Security.Current.UserRole': static types cannot be used as type arguments**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with where you're trying to use the class - it has everything to do with the fact that you can't use a static class as a type argument. Given that you can't create an instance of a static class, how could a `List<UserRole>` ever be useful?

I *strongly* suspect that those classes shouldn't be static classes to start with - why on earth would you want them to be?

(It's also not clear why they should be nested classes, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Actually my requirement is like i have a User which contain List of Roles and i would like access this current user to entire application without creating instance of that. Please suggest best solution for the same. your answer would be appreciated!!

Comment: @imdadhusen: Well, aside from the fact that I would question the wisdom of that design in the first place (statics tend to make testing hard, for one thing) just because the *list* variable is static doesn't mean the *class* (UserRole) has to be static. If you want instances of roles, it *can't* be static - and if you want each instance to have a different RoleID and RoleName, *those* shouldn't be static either. How confident are you in your understanding about what static means? It sounds like you may be a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you are trying to do. (although you're kind of going the wrong way about it.) The only Static Class should be User and they should not be Nested. There are a few other issues with your design but in the end everyone works differently.

This is one way you could have a List within a Static Class.

```
        public static class CurrentUser           
        {              
            public static int UserID { get; set; }              
            public static string UserName { get; set;   }


            public static List<UserRole> Role()
            {
                //Call another class with method to fill the list
                AnotherClass _anotherClass = new AnotherClass();
                return _anotherClass.Roles();

            }
        }
```

Then have a non-static UserRole

```
public  class UserRole         
        {              
        public  int RoleID { get; set; }     
        public  string RoleName { get; set; }      
        }
```

And the class where you retrieve your data from should contain a method to fill the List

```
            public class AnotherClass
        {
            public List<UserRole> Roles()
            {
                 List<UserRole> outList = new List<UserRole>();
                 //Fill the List with your UserRoles
                 foreach (object MyData in MyDataList)
                 {
                     UserRole myRole = new UserRole();
                     outList.Add(myRole);
                 }

                 return outList;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you cannot use UserRole as a type for the List.
Since it is a static class it would not make really sense. A list is made of objects that are instances of a class. There is no such thing as an instance for static class.

You should reconsider your design, you have some serious flaw in it.

Comment: Actually my requirement is like i have a User which contain List of Roles and i would like access this current user to entire application without creating instance of that. Please suggest best solution for the same. your answer would be appreciated!!