# C# - initialize static class as non-static class?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Connection
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Connection(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

Now I need this class as-is, but in part of my project I would really use class like this:

```
public static class Connection
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }

    static Connection()
    {
    }
}
```

Is there any way of merging this code together, so I can use both versions of this class in my project (somewhere I want to have a static, single instance of Connection, but somewhere else I want to have a list of Connections)?

Comment: You want a singleton, or a static reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can merge code like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Connection
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public Connection(string userName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public static Connection Default { get; set; }

    static Connection()
    {
        Default = new Connection("username");
    }

}
```

... and use it like this:

```
List<Connection> connections = new List<Connection>();
```

.. or like this:

```
string defaultConnectionUserName = Connection.Default.UserName;
```

Comment: Also gives you the ability to do `List<Connection> ...`, the other part of the question

Comment: your default connection creates a connection with an hard-coded user named "username". I can't grasp how it can be useful.

Comment: @LuisFilipe, it is just an example. You can read default username from `web.config` or `app.config` or database et al.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a static class as a type argument. Therefore in your circumstance you cannot have:

```
public List<Connection> { get; set; }
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092949/how-to-create-static-class-list-property-inside-static-class) answer by Jon Skeet for more information.

I suggest looking into the SOLID principles of object oriented programming and trying to abstract the functionality of the "connection" class out into multiples. If you provide more information on what you're trying to do I'll gladly make suggestions.